# How to copy the one static hashmap to another static hashmap

Tags: java, android

How to copy the static one(A) hashmap values to static another(B) hashmap but if change any value in B Hashmap the should not be reflect in the A HashMap

Example

```
public static HashMap<String,String> firstHashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
firstHashMap.put("1","A");
firstHashMap.put("2","B");

public static HashMap<String,String> secondHashMap = new HashMap<String,String>(firstHashMap);
secondHashMap.put("3","c");
secondHashMap.put("4","d");
```

Problem:
while doing like that the `firstHashMap` has contain the `secondHashMap` values also

How we can achieve this?
I need `firstHashMap` should contain only `firstHashMap` values and `secondHashMap` should contain both of them.

And also i tried making `secondHashMap.clone();`

Comment: Have you tried `putAll(secondMap)`? Do ypu want changes to firstMap to be immediately visible in the secondMap? Or is it a one time addition of all values from one map to the other

Comment: "*while doing like that the `firstHashMap` has contain the `secondHashMap` values also*" no after `secondHashMap = new HashMap<String,String>(firstHashMap)` `secondHashMap` will copy values of `firstHashMap`. That is it. If you later will add something to `firstHashMap` you will not see it in `secondHashMap` and vice versa, if you put something in `secondHashMap` you will not see it in `firstHashMap`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `putAll`?

```
public static HashMap<String, String> firstHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
    firstHashMap.put("1", "A");
    firstHashMap.put("2", "B");
}
public static HashMap<String, String> secondHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
    secondHashMap.put("3", "c");
    secondHashMap.put("4", "d");
    secondHashMap.putAll(firstHashMap);
}
```

It would replace values for keys in common (which you don't have here), but also put new key-value pairs.